# Combing multiple rows with same ForeignKey fields through query

Tags: python, django, aggregate, django-queryset

Current Model.objects.all() creates:

```
 FK Column  Column1  Column2  Column3
  Zone 1        19      23       67
  Zone 2        45      12       76
  Zone 1        23      98       34
  Zone 2        12      56       23
```

Expected Results:

```
 FK Column  Column1  Column2  Column3
  Zone 1        42      101       111
  Zone 2        57      68        99
```

The FKs are automatically combined into a single row.

which query should I use exactly for achieving this?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect? A list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `.values(..)` together with an `.annotate(..)` and `.order_by(..)`:

```
Model.objects.values(
    'fk_column'
).annotate(
    sumcol1=Sum('col1'),
    sumcol2=Sum('col2'),
    sumcol3=Sum('col3'),
).order_by('fk_column')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` of `dict`ionaries. Each dictionary contains an `'fk_column'`, `'sumcol1'`, `'sumcol2'`, and `'sumcol3'`. These parameters can then be processed further.

Comment: Hi thanks. It solved my problem but what if i need the object name of the foreign key. It is currently returning pk.

Comment: @Ohid: then you can fetch it wit extra queries like `RelatedModel.objects.get(pk=some_pk)`, or `RelatedModel.objects.get(pk__in=list_of_pks)`.